# Squish alternative for Qt

Tags: python, qt, automated-tests, squish

I'm looking for an app that does something similar to Squish.

I'd like it to be able to test Qt apps, maybe a free/open-source app, maybe with acces to the  Qt API and a scripting language like Python for hand written test cases.

Comment: Did you look at QtTest module? http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qttest.html

Comment: @utdemir: QTest is useful for unit tests, not UI scripting. @Paul I think Squish is the best choice.

Comment: QtTest is not what I'm looking for, anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Paul did you find anything? Any recommendations besides Squish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gitorious.org/hooq/hooq - A framework for recording and playing back events in Qt4 applications.

also:

https://projects.forum.nokia.com/Testabilitydriver/wiki - TDriver, nokia's Testability Driver for Qt

If you're intent on exposing your UI through Python, you could always use the binding generator from [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/). While it's general intent is to expose Qt under the hood, you could just as easily expose the signal mechanisms for direct twiddling from python. Really thats all the UI testing would be anyway right? Triggering signal/slot impulses programatically.

Answer (score 2):

you can use Cobra (winLDTP) http://cobra.codeplex.com/, this framework can handle QT based app

Answer (score 2):

The **funq** project was created exactly for this need. As mentionned on the [github project page](https://github.com/parkouss/funq/):

> funq is a tool to write FUNctional tests for Qt applications using
>   python.

It is a free and open source tool. Feedback and contributions are welcome!

Comment: How would this compare to Squish pr ldtp ?